# How can I tell AngularJS to "refresh"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a click event that happens outside the scope of my custom directive, so instead of using the "ng-click" attribute, I am using a jQuery.click() listener and calling a function inside my scope like so:

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
  scope.close();
);
```

close() is a simple function that looks like this:

```
scope.close = function() {
  scope.isOpen = false;
}
```

In my view, I have an element with "ng-show" bound to isOpen like this:

```
<div ng-show="isOpen">My Div</div>
```

When debugging, I am finding that close() is being called, isOpen is being updated to false, but the AngularJS view is not updating. Is there a way I can manually tell Angular to update the view? Or is there a more "Angular" approach to solving this problem that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 347, accepted):

The solution was to call...

```
$scope.$apply();
```

...in my jQuery event callback.

Comment: This link will be helpfull, I think.
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: shouldn't that be `$scope.$apply();`?

Comment: You can use both $scope or scope, it's just an notation difference but it results in the same.

Comment: @ErichBSchulz -Often in directives, I see scope used without the $ which I believe is likely to differentiate between it and the '$scope' that gets injected into controllers.  In controllers, it is important to reference by $scope so Angular knows what dependency to inject, whereas in a directive link function, it always passes the same 4 elements by ordinal and does not require a specific name (scope, element, attrs, controller).

Answer (score 45):

## Why `$apply` should be called?

**TL;DR**:
`$apply` should be called whenever you want to apply changes made **outside** of Angular world.

---

Just to update [*@Dustin's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305082/4927984), here is an explanation of **what** [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) exactly does and **why** it works.

> `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of
>   the AngularJS framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the AngularJS framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   [exception handling](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler), [executing watches](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

Angular allows any value to be used as a binding target. Then at the end of any JavaScript code turn, it checks to see if the value has changed. 
That step that checks to see if any binding values have changed actually has a method, `$scope.$digest()`<sup>[1](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)</sup>. We almost never call it directly, as we use `$scope.$apply()` instead (which will call `$scope.$digest`).

Angular only monitors variables used in expressions and anything inside of a `$watch` living inside the scope. So if you are changing the model outside of the Angular context, you will need to call `$scope.$apply()` for those changes to be propagated, otherwise Angular will not know that they have been changed thus the binding will not be updated<sup>[2](http://haroldrv.com/2015/02/using-scope-apply-in-angularjs/)</sup>.

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
$route.reload();
```

remember to inject `$route` to your controller.

Comment: Also, when using ui-router, make sure to use `$state.reload()`

Comment: This was super helpful for our screenshot tests! We mock out state but sometimes don't necessarily have watchers that watch the changes, which can result in confusing failures or intermittent failures. But being able to reload the scope like this helps combat that.

Answer (score 1):

While the following did work for me:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

it required a lot more setup and the use of both `.$on` and `.$broadcast` to work or potentially `$.watch`.

However, the following required much less code and worked like a charm.

```
$timeout(function() {});
```

Adding a timeout right after the update to the scope variable allowed AngularJS to realize there was an update and apply it by itself.