# un-hiding a data-bound thing ( ng-model or {{food.foo}} ) breaks the binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My problem:  I can modify my model fine, and the changes are reflected in my view, *as long as* my view is hidden.  As soon as my view is un-hidden, changes made to scope.food.foo from timeouts, event handlers, etc. no longer apply.  This is all within a directive.

Fiddley:  http://jsfiddle.net/9T9qE/1/

I *am* using an object as my model (instead of using the scope as my model, which [causes problems with inheritance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m))  That is, I'm using scope.food.foo instead of simply scope.foodFoo

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

js:

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.directive("myDirective", function() {
    var d = {};
    d.restrict = "E";
    d.template = '<div ng-show="food.show">hi, I like <input type="text" ng-model="food.foo">   and, in case you forgot, that\'s {{food.foo}}</div><button ng-click="food.show = true">show me</button>';
    d.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.food = {};
        scope.food.foo = "pie";
        scope.food.show = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("timeout: setting scope.food.foo = 'cake'");
            scope.food.foo = "cake";
        }, 6000);
    };
    return d;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How can I tell AngularJS to "refresh"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304728)

looks like the answer is scope.$appy() - that worked for me. http://jsfiddle.net/XR9s2/1

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("timeout: setting food.foo = 'cake'");
        scope.$apply(function() { food.foo = "cake"; });
    }, 6000);
```

This article, referenced from the above question, helped me too:
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

**Edit**: from that article:

> Sometimes I see examples where data is updated, and then $scope.$apply() is called with no  arguments. This achieves the desired result, but misses some opportunities.
>
> If your code isn’t wrapped in a function passed to $apply, and it throws an error, that error is thrown outside of AngularJS, which means any error handling being used in your application is going to miss it. $apply not only runs your code, but it runs it in a try/catch so your error is always caught, and the $digest call is in a finally clause, meaning it will run regardless of an error being thrown. That’s pretty nice.

I changed my code above to reflect that:  instead of changing the value, then using scope.$apply(), I did scope.$apply(function() { /* change value */ });

Comment: Good explanation of how to use `$scope.$apply( function() { ... } );`