# ng-repeat doesn't duplicate data when list gets updated dynamically

Tags: angularjs, html, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am adding data to an array dynamically and trying to duplicate divs using ng-repeat.

If the data were added initially it renders properly, but not if we add data dynamically later.

angular

```
var app = angular.module('game',[]);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var json = [];
  $scope.setlobbyData = function(obj){
      $scope.json = obj;
      $scope.lobbyData = $scope.json;
  };
  });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="i in lobbyData">some data</div>
</div>
```

js

```
var ssr = {
    "0": {
        "tradeSpread": 0,
        "minBuyIn": 10,
        "minPlayers": 2,

    },
    "1": {
        "tradeSpread": 0,
        "minBuyIn": 10,
        "minPlayers": 2,

    }
};
angular.element($("#foreignExchangeMain")).scope().setlobbyData(ssr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution could be to call the

```
$scope.$apply();
```

See here:
[How can I tell AngularJS to "refresh"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304728/how-can-i-tell-angularjs-to-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this post for updating scope data from outside angular:

[AngularJS access scope from outside js function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function)

Answer (score 0):

used $apply to refresh

```
 var scope = angular.element($("#foreignExchangeMain")).scope();
        scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.json = ssr;
            scope.setlobbyData(ssr)

        });
```