# ng-show not working properly in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to show element based on the value of property inside controller.

```
eReaderBook.directive("controlTools", function () {
return {
    replace : true,
    restrict : "E",
    templateUrl : "assets/directives/controlstools.html",
    controller : function ($scope) {
        $scope.visible = false;
    },
    link : function (scope, el, attr) {

       el.bind("mouseover",function()
        {
           console.log(scope.visible)
           scope.visible = true;
        });
        el.bind("mouseout",function()
        {
            console.log(scope.visible)
             scope.visible = false;
        })
    }
};
```

});

```
<div class="menuitem"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><span ng-show="visible" class="menutext">Toc</span></div>
```

Inside the directive I have a controller defined with `$scope.visible = false`. Everything works fine on page load. I want to change the state to `$scope.visible = true` on `mouseover` and `$scope.visible = false` on `mouseout`. Why does `scope.visible = true;` not affect `ng-show`?

Comment: DOM events are outside of Angular. You need to inform Angular of the change with `$scope.$apply()`. Angular already has directives for this, so you don't need to create a new one.

Comment: Your event handling happens outside the *`$digest`-cycle*. Use [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) or better [`ngMouseenter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell AngularJS to "refresh"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304728/how-can-i-tell-angularjs-to-refresh)

Comment: Why not use `ng-mouseover="visible = true"` and `ng-mouseleave="visible = false"`? I think this is easier. E.g. `<span ng-show="visible" ng-mouseover="visible = true" ng-mouseleave="visible = false" class="menutext">Toc</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
You just forgot to add scope: true that is responsible to share scope.

return {
  replace: true,
  restrict: "E",
  scope: true,
  templateUrl: "assets/directives/controlstools.html",
```